# How can I get a 'get' request to run on a schedule in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

The function I would like this function to run by itself at time intervals. As it is now I have to visit the '/getCompanyInfo' path to trigger it. I would like it to run every minute as if I was visiting the '/getCompanyInfo' path each minute. The app is on Heroku and I would like the function to execute without any pages open.

The original function that is triggered by visiting the path.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

/**
 * getCompanyInfo ()
 */
app.get('/getCompanyInfo', function(req,res){

    const companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;
    console.log(companyID)
    const url = OAuthClient.environment.production ;

    oauthClient.makeApiCall({url: url + 'v3/company/0000000000/salesreceipt/8?minorversion=41'})
        .then(function(authResponse){
            console.log("The response for API call is :"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authResponse)));
            res.send(authResponse);
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
});
```

One of my attempts here was to put it in a function that executes each minute using node-schedule.
This one doesn't do anything other than print 'This will run once a minute.' to the console.
I tried removing

```
app.get(function(req,res){
```

and the

```
})
```

below it but that made the app (hosted on Heroku) fail to build.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
console.log('This will run once a minute.');
app.get(function(req,res){

    const companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;
    console.log(companyID)
    const url = OAuthClient.environment.production ;

    oauthClient.makeApiCall({url: url + 'v3/company/0000000000/salesreceipt/8?minorversion=41'})
        .then(function(authResponse){
            console.log("The response for API call is :"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authResponse)));
            res.send(authResponse);
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
});

});
```

More Context:
It is inside an app I have on Heroku. I would like to set the app to make a requests for JSON data from the API every x time without me having to touch it.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't make any sense to call `app.get()` repeatedly.  All that does is register a route handler (it doesn't execute the route handler) and the last thing you want to do is to register the same event handler more than once. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Are you trying to get some web page in a browser to update automatically?  Or something else?

Comment: I would like to set the app to make a requests for JSON data from the API every x time without me having to touch it. The end goal is obtaining JSON data from a call to an API at x time on repeat. app.get() is just the function I'm working from. Like I said in OP, the app doesn't build when I get rid of the app.get() wrapping.

Comment: Then, just put the API call in a plain function (no `app.get()` involved) and call that function repeatedly using either `setInterval()` or some other favorite scheduling tool.  Your code shows you doing `res.send()` which make no sense in this context.  You  still haven't said what you want to DO with the result of that API call.  It's really hard to help when you won't tell us the REAL problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: "Then, just put the API call in a plain function." That turned out to be my issue. I tried this before and must have had Heroku issues or something wrong somewhere because it works now. I want to make another API call with the info, parse it, and send it to Facebook's API, but I've been discouraged from asking for more than one thing. Sorry, I'm new to Node and Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get` initializes api handler - e.g. this is your api route definition - the thing that will respond when you call `GET /getCompanyInfo` via web browser or some other client. You should not redefine it regularly with your scheduled action.

The failed build after you've removed the route handler is probably because of the `res.send(authResponse);` left behind.

You could have something like:

```
// function that will be used to get the data
const getCompanyInfo = (done) => {
  const companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId
  console.log(companyID)
  const url = OAuthClient.environment.production

  oauthClient.makeApiCall({url: url + 'v3/company/0000000000/salesreceipt/8?minorversion=41'})
    .then((authResponse) => {
      console.log("The response for API call is :"+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authResponse)))
      done(authResponse)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e)
    })
}

// this will trigger the function regularly on the specified interval
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', () => {
  getCompanyInfo((companyInfo) => {
    // ...do whatever you want with the info
  })
})

// this will return you the data by demand, when you call GET /getCompanyInfo via browser
app.get('/getCompanyInfo', function(req,res) {
  getCompanyInfo((companyInfo) => {
    res.send(companyInfo)
  })
})
```

Comment: Embarrassing. For some reason this works after I tried it a second time (The top part of your code). The first time I tried to do this the obvious way I got 'Application Error' so I assumed something more complex would be needed since I am new to NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has an add on called [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) that does what you want. The node-schedule npm package might do the job, but as you mentioned, you probably aren't going to be able to see the execution/results/logs of your jobs that run every 24 hours without making some interface for it on your own.

For your issue, calling `app.get` doesn't make a lot of sense. That's just telling node about the route. Assuming you have your `/getCompanyInfo` route up and running, you just need to call it in your scheduled job, not re-register it every time.

You could also just do this (`http` being the http client you're using):

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', async function(){
    console.log('This will run once a minute.');
    const result = await http.get('/getCompanyInfo');
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: While I have you, since you're a 6k user: Is Heroku okay for production? Sensitive data that had to be sent each day using something like this for a client? btw, aivo's answer ended up working with 'node-schedule' and his answer was something I attempted but messed up somehow due to being a novice. Your and his answer is illuminating and hopefully not a blight for SO to leave the question up.

Comment: You should upvote the answers that have helped you solve your problem. Also, yes, Heroku is perfectly safe. Many people use Heroku for production. With that being said, your application is only as secure as you make it.